# Angular: Why Won't Model Update Outside Of View In Same Controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-view

I have found a number of posts talking about models/views not updating, but I still can't figure this out. I'm new to Angular, btw so I suspect this is noob issue.

I have the below Angular app.

**When the text input `test_var` is edited, the edited value isn't updated in the sidebar, but it is in the view. Why and how do I fix it?**

This works when I don't use views and routes.

I've tried a sidebar controller, but no difference. I've tried `$rootScope`, which partially worked (it broke other functionality), but I'd prefer not to use a global scope.

Thanks for taking a look.

---

### HTML

```html
<body>

 <div ng-app="rxApp" ng-controller="WizardCtrl">
  
  <div class="ng-view">
  </div>

  <div class="sidebar">
   <span ng-bind="test_var"></span>
  </div>

 </div>

</body>
```

### View (One.html)

```html
<input ng-model="test_var" />
 
<span ng-bind="test_var"></span>
```

### Controller

```js
rxApp.controller( 'WizardCtrl', function ( $scope, $http, $routeParams, $location, FileUploader ) {

   $scope.test_var = 'please work!';

)};
```

### Routes

```js
rxApp.config(['$routeProvider',
 function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/one', {
   templateUrl: 'templates/one.html',
   controller: 'WizardCtrl'
  }).
  when('/two', {
   templateUrl: 'templates/two.html',
   controller: 'WizardCtrl'
  }).
  otherwise({
   redirectTo: '/one'
  });
 }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers are disposed when transmuting routes.
As for Best Practice you should create a Service to handle that data. You should not use controllers to carry data between views. In your case, the problem is Controllers are disposed when transmuting routes.

See the angular docs on how to use controllers correctly. [http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#controller)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Prateek. That link doesn't work. I assume you mean: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller ?

Comment: you can read this for better understanding  : [controller concept](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#controller)

Comment: I've been looking into services and I think that's the way to go for my app overall. To get this one view to work would you suggest I move the sidebar into the view html? Is that the only way or is there another way? Like using partials (I'm researching now)? The sidebar will need to be referenced in all of my views.

Comment: I didn't understand your sidebar issue properly. But I think you should keep the sidebar in separate view only. I suggest you make different controller for the sidebar and main view. Transfer the scope value using service (though as a work round I've used several things like angular Values and localStorage sometime. PS don't judge me). try it first or else make a cope snippet in jsfiddle an update your question, will solve out for you

Comment: Prateek, quick update for you. I implemented a service to share data. I also made use of Angular UI Router so I could use multiple views (main and sidebar). Thanks again for your help. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the making of model variables.

***You have to have a dot in model. Make your model point to an object.***

So in your controller do like this -

```
rxApp.controller('WizardCtrl',function($scope, $http, $routeParams,$location, FileUploader){

    $scope.test ={
         var : 'please work!'
       };

)};
```

**View (One.html)**

```
<input ng-model="test.var" />

<span ng-bind="test.var"></span>
```

**HTML**

```
<body>

    <div ng-app="rxApp" ng-controller="WizardCtrl">

        <div class="ng-view">
        </div>

        <div class="sidebar">
            <span ng-bind="test.var"></span>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

To read more about scope go through this [UnderStanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes%22Understanding%20scopes%22%22)

Comment: Thanks Amit, but `$scope.test = { var = 'please work!' };` is syntactically incorrect. This is correct: `$scope.test = { var: 'please work!' };` And I saw no difference the results.

Comment: i agree, my mistake didn't noticed, tell me about the functionality its working or not.